# WIQL query to get all item under a workitem

Tags: tfs, wiql

I am looking for a query where i can return all work items and their relation from a area path.

for example : project 1

i need all Featured all Userstories mapped to it all workitem and Bug mapped to userstories,

in short if i took a bug from the object i need somthing like parent id where i can match with the userstory.

```
string query1 = " SELECT * FROM WorkItemLinks " +
                    " WHERE ( [System.IterationPath] Under 'iteration1' )" +
                    " AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward' )" +
                    " ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]";
```

which throwing an error like below

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[System.IterationPath]».
```

when i checked the dll's are refereed correctly and when i re wrote the query like this the query is working fine

```
 string query = " SELECT * FROM WorkItems"+
                           " WHERE  ( [System.IterationPath] Under 'iteration1' )" +
                           //" AND  ([System.State] = 'Active' OR  [System.State] = 'Assessed' ) "+
                           //" AND  ( [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate] <= '09/13/2017' AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate] >= '09/13/2017' )"+
                           " ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]";
```

but this query result does not give the relation ship that if a work item mapped as a child to other i need parent id in the work item object. how to get that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query:

Install Nuget Package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for the project.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;

namespace _0925_WIQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                  new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC"));
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));


            string query1= " SELECT * FROM WorkItemLinks " +
                    " WHERE ( Source.[System.IterationPath] Under 'TeamProject\\Iteration 1' )" +
                    " AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward' )" +
                    " ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]";

            Query query = new Query(workItemStore, query1);
            WorkItemLinkInfo[] witLinkInfos = query.RunLinkQuery();

            foreach (WorkItemLinkInfo witinfo in witLinkInfos)
            {

                .......
            }
```

Besides, you can also use [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor). If you want to get all the parent workitems (IDs) from a specific child work item (ID), you can use below WIQL:

```
SELECT                      
        [System.Id],
        [System.WorkItemType],
        [System.Title],
        [System.AssignedTo],
        [System.State]
FROM workitemLinks
WHERE ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')
AND ([Target].[System.Id] = 25)
ORDER BY [System.Id]
MODE (Recursive, ReturnMatchingChildren)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but still the query1 is not working and getting error like

An exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @AJI I have updated the query1 in above answer, please try it again with  the updated query1, make sure you used the **[Query.RunLinkQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.query.runlinkquery.aspx)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated code thats work fine. as Target Id is current workitem and source is parent ID. Now since its getting from WorkitemLinks am only getting few items. Is there any way i can Join the Wok item query and workitemLink query to get one result which have all information for the workitem like assigned to total,completed and remaining hours etc along with Source Id. Thank you so much

Comment: @AJI We can not achieve that, wiql is not like the sql.