# WIQL select only System.* columns (Similar to SQL [select [table].* from [table]])

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, workitem, wiql

In SQL you can select all the columns from a table by using * or table.*

Is there a way to do this in WIQL?

For example : `Select [System].* From WorkItems Where [System.Title] = '$($incident.Title)'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359173/11954025

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine having wildcard under `SELECT` statement. If you want to use wildcard type in the criteria then you probably wanna do something like this :

```
$qCriteria="%"+$($incident.Title)+"%"

$query=@"
Select
    *
From
    WorkItems
Where
    [System.Title] = '$qCriteria'

"@
```

Here is a sample of a query that I used in SCCM

```
$query=@"
SELECT
    *
FROM
    meta_class
WHERE
    __Class LIKE "%network%"
"@

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_CODE" -ComputerName 'serverName' -Query $query
```